# Is all android devices compatible with dji SDK mobile?

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I would like to know if most android devices are compatible if I make an app with dji sdk mobile.

https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/application-development-workflow/workflow-prerequisits.html

It shows some compatible android devices, but is it only for dev purpose, or it is really the only devices that will be compatible if I make an app with this sdk ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer:
Those are some devices that are compatible with DJI Mobile SDK. But other devices that are API 19 or above should work just fine.

Other Considerations:

On the end of the [page](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/application-development-workflow/workflow-prerequisits.html) it says in gray
"Note: Support for additional Android devices available as testing and development continues.". This means that those devices were fully tested with the skd and everything works fine on then, other devices were not fully tested yet.

Keep in mind that DJI Mobile SDK is not compatible with androidX - just saying it because I've migrated my app to androidX in the past and it fully stopped working!

Also, in some devices the FPV video might not work, it was the case with my Samsung Galaxy Tab A. I believe this is an issue with the video decoder on that device since my Asus Zenfone Live that has the same API level 22 (Android 5.1.1) worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the above answer; basically, the SDK is not compatible with x86 devices.

Cut from README:

> Mobile SDK 4.7 and later versions are incompatible with x86 devices:
>   Since v4.7, Mobile SDK has included FFMpeg lib to provide the
>   transcoded video feed, but FFMpeg x86 .SO ﬁles will lead to the
>   runtime crash when the target API of APP is larger than 23(included).